# Unhandled exception at Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location

Tags: c++

I am not the best with c/c++ code but ill do my best to explain.

so I am watching an OpenCL tutorial video with visual studio, and right when it gets here(https://youtu.be/45MIykWJ-C4?t=2268), it works for the guy writing the code  but when I give it a try this is what pops up

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUdXE.png)

```
#include"shaderClass.h"

// Reads a text file and outputs a string with everything in the text file
std::string get_file_contents(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (in)
    {
        std::string contents;
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        contents.resize(in.tellg());
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
        in.close();
        return(contents);
    }
    throw(errno); //error here I am using opengl from the video heres where I am
}

// Constructor that build the Shader Program from 2 different shaders
Shader::Shader(const char* vertexFile, const char* fragmentFile)
{
    // Read vertexFile and fragmentFile and store the strings
    std::string vertexCode = get_file_contents(vertexFile);
    std::string fragmentCode = get_file_contents(fragmentFile);

    // Convert the shader source strings into character arrays
    const char* vertexSource = vertexCode.c_str();
    const char* fragmentSource = fragmentCode.c_str();

    // Create Vertex Shader Object and get its reference
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    // Attach Vertex Shader source to the Vertex Shader Object
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    // Compile the Vertex Shader into machine code
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // Create Fragment Shader Object and get its reference
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    // Attach Fragment Shader source to the Fragment Shader Object
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    // Compile the Vertex Shader into machine code
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // Create Shader Program Object and get its reference
    ID = glCreateProgram();
    // Attach the Vertex and Fragment Shaders to the Shader Program
    glAttachShader(ID, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(ID, fragmentShader);
    // Wrap-up/Link all the shaders together into the Shader Program
    glLinkProgram(ID);

    // Delete the now useless Vertex and Fragment Shader objects
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

}

// Activates the Shader Program
void Shader::Activate()
{
    glUseProgram(ID);
}

// Deletes the Shader Program
void Shader::Delete()
{
    glDeleteProgram(ID);
}
```

Comment: Iit sti does not work even though it got edited

Answer (score 2):

The file you're trying to open doesn't exist. You can easily see this using a debugger.

Comment: how do i do this, Im not the best with vs

Comment: bro, I dont how or what that is. please tell me

Comment: It is not working

Comment: When you tell Visual Studio to debug your program, it uses the debug directory as "the current directory".  You're probably passing an incomplete filepath like `"vertecies.txt"` instead of `"C:/Users/cyberblade/docs/code/opengl/vertecies.txt"`, and since `vertecies.txt` isn't in the debug directory, then there's no file to open, and you've coded it to throw that `int` exception when that occurs.

Comment: It is wherever the `Shader` gets constructed. The filenames are the variables of the constructor. Open the call hierarchy or stacktrace window, when the exception is thrown.